# Sort HTML "LI" by Repeated Times and alphabetically

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

Question :How can I order HTML Tag("LI") by following rule

Rules are

1. Start with ordered "Repeated Times" :li  (DESC)
2. Then order alphabetically

I want to order HTML Tag("LI")

1. I will put HTML Tag("Li") into Array   (ok)
2. Sorting Array by rule (not ok)
3. put back to html  (ok)

for example

**Input**

```
 
  put "li" into "array" 
[R,What,JIMMY,O,The,News,Fusion,JIMMY,Sc,What,AgentsOfShield,WABCE,Black,Alad,The,2020,JIMMY,News,Dancing,Fusion,Fusion,R,What,JIMMY,O,The,News,Fusion]
```

**output** (order should be like this)

```
 
    [Fusion, JIMMY, News, The, What, O, R, 2020, AgentsOfShield, Alad,Black,Dancing,Sc ,WABCE ,Fusion ,JIMMY ,News ,The ,What ,O ,R ,Fusion ,JIMMY ,News ,The ,What ,Fusion ,JIMMY]
```

However,the output order is wrong in my code .
**wrong output**

```
 
[Fusion, JIMMY, What, The, Fusion, JIMMY, News, What, News, O, JIMMY, The, R, Fusion, The, AgentsOfShield, O, JIMMY, R, Fusion, Sc, News, Dancing, Black, WABCE, What, Alad, 2020]
```

Please check the codehttp://jsfiddle.net/BrianHCM/9CVHx/5/

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Eric, fixed my format error

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BrianHCM/9CVHx/3/

Comment: Edit your fiddle into the actual question as well.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr with 1rep .. he can't do it.

Comment: What? Its their question, of course the OP can edit their own question?. And then they can edit in the code in code tags, like they have done for their sample data. What can't the OP do exactly?

Comment: hi @LegoStormtroopr ,I made some change, is it right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the updated code, it show's unique words with their counts ordered. I left a comment of where you can append the original LI's repeated but ordered instead of uniques.

Hope this help.

```
function Randomize() {
    var ul = document.querySelector('#editor_0_ddList_0');
        lis = ul.querySelectorAll('li'),
        words = {},
        result = [];

    //Get the words and counts
    for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
        var li = lis[i],
            name = li.innerHTML;

        //Set some data of the word with the founded LI's
        if(words[name] == null){ //Create the object
            words[name] = {
                word : name,
                lis : [li],
                count : 1
            };
        }else{ //Update
            words[name].lis.push(li);
            words[name].count++;
        }

        //Clean the li
        li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
    }

    //Set the result array with the words and datas
    for(var word in words) result.push(words[word]);

    //Sort all
    result.sort(function (a, b){
        return (a.count > b.count) ? -1 : 
        (a.count == b.count ) ? a.name > b.name ? -1 : 1 : 1;
    });

    //Append ordered
    for(var r = 0; r < result.length; r++){
        var li = document.createElement('LI');
        li.innerHTML = result[r].word + ' x' + result[r].count;

        //Make a for of result[r].lis and append to UL if you want to use the originals and repeated LI's

        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you 
sorry, my express let you misunderstood
use your code, I got this
[Fusion x4, JIMMY x4 ,News x3 ,The x3 , What x3 ,O x2 , R x2 ,Dancing x1 ,2020 x1, Alad x1 , Black x1 ,WABCE x1 , AgentsOfShield x1, Sc x1 ]

Actually,I wish I could got this
[Fusion, JIMMY, News, The, What, O, R, 2020, AgentsOfShield, Alad,Black,Dancing,Sc ,WABCE ,Fusion ,JIMMY ,News ,The ,What ,O ,R ,Fusion ,JIMMY ,News ,The ,What ,Fusion ,JIMMY]</code></pre>